# Cannot install generator-angular2

Tags: node.js, yeoman, angular

When `install generator-angular2`, error shows:

> npm WARN ENOENT ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular2/package.json'
>
> npm WARN ENOENT ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular2/node_modules/yeoman-assert/package.json'
>
> npm ERR! code 1

Then run `yo angular2`:

> You don't seem to have a generator with the name angular2 installed.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem faced by me while isntalling Grunt.js today ,you will need to add -g flag to your command which will install it globally.

```
npm install -g <package_name>
```

In your case it would be

```
npm install -g generator-angular2
```

Comment: @Anne Are u still getting some messages ?

Answer (score -2):

I had this problem with run the command without "sudo".

example:

```
npm install -g generator-angular2
```

show error.

If I typed

```
sudo npm install -g generator-angular2
```

work fine.

In my case the problem is the initial instalation of npm, I installed with sudo.
When I need install something of npm I need sudo.

Comment: Not advised to use sudo with npm, if you're having to sudo a package you have bigger problems.